# Does C'tron always start at LV 22? Or does he match Lea to a point?

Tags: cross-code

Does C'tron always start at LVL 22? Or does he match Lea to a point?

Because I first talked to him while Lea was at LVL 22, but if I levelled up before meeting him, would he have too?

If so, when does he stop levelling?